# ktor DuplicatePluginException – conflicting application plugin is already installed with the same key as `OpenTelemetry`

Tags: ktor, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

I am trying to integrate `aspect.io` (which acts as opentelmetry collector) into our microservice written using ktor-2.0

The changes are:

**buid.gradle.kts**

```
application {
  mainClass.set(appMainClass)
  applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf(
    "-javaagent:$buildDir/otel/otel-javaagent.jar",
    "-Dotel.service.name=mservice",
    "-Dotel.exporter.otlp.traces.endpoint=https://otelcol.aspecto.io:4317",
    "-Dotel.logs.otlp.headers=Authorization=<auth-token>"
  )
}

val openTelemetry: Configuration by configurations.creating

dependencies {
  ...
  implementation(platform("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-bom:1.32.0"))
  implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api")
  implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-extension-kotlin")
  implementation("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-ktor-2.0:1.31.0-alpha")
  implementation("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0:1.31.0-alpha")
  openTelemetry("io.opentelemetry.javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent:1.31.0")
  ...
}
```

**App.kt**

```
fun Application.main() {
  ...
  
  install(KtorServerTracing) {
    setOpenTelemetry(GlobalOpenTelemetry.get())
  }

  ...
}
```

The changes are inspired by the open source example available [here](https://gitlab.com/gmariotti/ktor-opentelemetry/-/tree/main?ref_type=heads).

With this configuration, I get the following error consistently:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.ktor.server.application.DuplicatePluginException: Please make sure that you use unique name for the plugin and don't install it twice. Conflicting application plugin is already installed with the same key as `OpenTelemetry`
    at io.ktor.server.application.ApplicationPluginKt.install(ApplicationPlugin.kt:114)
    at com.knidal.platform.luna.AppKt.main(App.kt:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:207)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:332)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:356)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:32)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:312)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:338)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:310)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:150)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:277)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:216)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:23)
```

Not sure why it throws a `DuplicatePluginException`. There is no other place where the plugin is being initialized. One thing to note is we use `application.conf` in our service. Not sure if it is related to that or not.

Any directional guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the exception occur in the "production" environment or the tests? Can you check that the `Application.main` method is called only once when defined in the `application.conf` or via a direct call but not both?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman it occurs in "development" environment, not in tests. There is a section the `.conf` like the following `  application `{ modules = [com.AppKt.main]
  }`. I don't explicitly call it anywhere. In gradle there is an `application` section where I define the `mainClass` and also put in the `defaultArgs` to run the `opentelemetry javaagent`.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman btw, this is using ktor server, not client.